# SQL Statement is failing due to pound (#) sign

Tags: php, sql, odbc

My PHP SQL Statement is failing due to pound (#) sign.  How can I get around this. (Other than fixing the database name?)

```
$sql = "SELECT CMCD, TK#, TECH, STATS from LIB.TICKET FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY ";
$rs = odbc_exec($conn,$sql);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping your column name in brackets `[TK#]`

Comment: Actually problem was with pound sign in PHP variable...  TK# = odbc_result($rs,"TK#");  Changed TK# to TK and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Try quoting the field names

```
$sql = "SELECT `CMCD`, `TK#`, `TECH`, `STATS` from LIB.TICKET FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY ";
$rs = odbc_exec($conn,$sql);
```